# Toolbar add button

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have an app that has an `NSToolbar`, and one of the toolbar items is an add button (Of type `NSButton`).
Here is what mine currently looks like:

[image: Add button]

That is the state of the button untouched (ie no mouse hover, no mouse press)

I'm trying to achieve something like what Xcode has:

[image: Xcode add button]

That is once again the untouched state. You can see that it's completely transparent except for the image. However, when you hover over the button, it turns into this:

[image: Xcode button highlight]

You can see a slight color over the button.

How would I acheive this using Storyboards? I tried changing the style of the button to many things, but none helped.

Or do I even need a button? I tried using just the `NSToolbarItem` with an image, but it doesn't have the highlight effect.

Comment: Which OS are you running? In case you're running the Monterey Beta, These highlights are something that changed in that OS.

Comment: @Alexander I'm currently running Monterey Beta, but I think this applies to macOS Big Sur as well.